# Truffle test to verify events can be queried by the address of the signing user?

Tags: events, private-key, signature, truffle-test

I'm trying to write a test which verifies I can query a given type of events by the user/address which sign them.

I would like to apply TDD (relevant to say I haven't made the implementation for this particular case yet).

I was expecting something like:

```
  describe('get user history', () => {
    it ('returns the events signed by the user', async () => {

      # create account for user 'john' with generated private key

      # submit transaction 'buyGroceries' with 'john' signature which should emit an event

      # submit transaction 'buyNewspaper' with random account which should emit an event

      # assert the first and only the first transaction is returned when query for the event type signed by 'john'

    });
  });
```

The problem with this is that I don't find any utils which allow me through truffle tests to create an account with a private key on its clean-room environment.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing Ganache.

Comment: As goodvibration suggested, try to install Ganache: https://truffleframework.com/ganache. Ganache provides you test accounts with their PK and addresses. Then you can simply address them inside your scripting test. Here and example https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#using-web3